# Apache user isn't able to connect to smtp (Centos)

Tags: php, apache, smtp, centos

I have a CentOS server with apache and SSMTP connected with my SMTP server.

If I try to send an email from the console, it works fine.
"ssmtp ...@gmail.com"  or  "mail ...@gmail.com"

But, if I make a php script to send an email, it works when I execute it from the console (php script.php), but it doesn't work when I execute it from the apache server (localhost/script.php).

Looking at the apache logs, i have seen that it can't connect to the smtp server (no more details in the log).

Apache is running with the "apache" user and when I execute ssmtp or similar from the console i'm using the root user, so I think the system is blocking the connection for apache user...

Some Ideas?? Thank you!

(I have tried to use PHPMailer, but it returns the same result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem. The trick was in the SELinux permissons.

I executed these commands and now it works like a charm :)

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1

setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail=1